# Bootstrap 4.0 alpha - Set column width in table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0 alpha (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/)..

I've created a table with 5 columns but the width is automatically configured. I want to set the width percentage per column.

I've tried using **class="col-xs-3" in th**, as suggested in stackoverflow, without success.

I've found a post about this question. While the title says He uses Bootstrap V4... He's really using bootstrap 3.3.7.
([How to specify responsive column width for table in Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131128/how-to-specify-responsive-column-width-for-table-in-bootstrap-v4))

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let expense of expenses">
      <td>{{expense.datetime | date}}</td>
      <td>{{expense.description}}</td>
      <td>{{expense.amount | currency:'USD':true}}</td>
      <td>{{expense.comment}}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: put your code here

Comment: done! I've edited my original post

Answer (score 3):

I migrated from 3.3 to 4 so there could be a little funkiness.

1. The div container that holds the table `col-xs-12` must be set
2. `tr` in `thead` must be set as a `row` and maybe the width `col-xs-12` set, depending on your needs
3. table class `table-responsive` is also dependent on your needs

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr class="row col-xs-12">
        <th class="col-xs-9">Location</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      ...
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldnt post sample code....... [link](https://pastebin.com/AL9cqnpH)

Comment: I fixed your code sample. When you are adding code and it immediately follows a numbered list, the indent is doubled (indent 8, not 4). That's why your code was hidden, it was being rendered by the browser as HTML, not as a code sample block. You can get around this using a `<!-- language:` tag, which is what I did. (Edit answer text to see example, if you want.)